# Can you import more than 10 years of data into R using the Bureau of Labor Statistics API?

Tags: r, api

I'm working with the Bureau of Labor Statistics (BLS) API in R for the first time. I'm trying to import tables into R using the API, but it looks like I can't import more than 10 years worth of data at a time. Is there any way to get around this (other than importing one decade at at time)?

Answer (score 0):

In the [readme of blsAPI](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/blsAPI/readme/README.html):

API Basics

The blsAPI package supports two versions of the BLS API. API Version 2.0 requires registration and offers greater query limits. It also allows users to request net and percent changes and series description information. See below for more details.

```
Service            Version 2.0 (Registered)     Version 1.0 (Unregistered)
Daily query limit           500                         25
Series per query limit      50                          25
Years per query limit       20                          10
Net/Percent Changes         Yes                         No
Optional annual averages    Yes                         No
Series description information (catalog)    Yes         No
```

So 10 years of data per query if you are not registered otherwise 20 years.